# error during execution on a method that I am not calling

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, compiler-errors

I am using a method of a class with 3 parameters as follows:

```
oEthereum.connect(oMyIP, oMyPort, oMyString);
```

There are 3 methods with the name "connect" but the compiler complains about the method with one parameter during the execution. Am I missing anything?

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEcNb.jpg)

The compiler show the following error message:

> The method connect(Node) in the type Ethereum is not applicable for
>   the arguments (String, int)

Regards,
Skydog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's running an overloaded method, so something like:

```
public void oEthereum.connect(String oMyIP, String oMyPort, String oMyString){
    connect(oMyIP);
    // do other stuff with oMyPort, oMyString
}
```

You need to verify that the 3 parameters you passed are valid, and any derived values that may be passed into the 1-parameter method would be valid.

Comment: Hi ergonaut, the definition of the variablen are these:
private static  String oMyIP = new String("127.0.0.1");
private static  int oMyPort = 30303;
private static String oMyString = new String("");

The method call is oEthereum.connect(oMyIP, oMyPort, oMyString);

The possible connect methods are these:
1.- void connect(InetAddress addr, int port, String remoteId);
2.- void connect(String ip, int port, String remoteId);
3.- void connect(Node node);

The compiler should take the method 2.-

Comment: The parameters are valid according to one of the method definitions, therefore it should work and the compiler shouln't complain

Comment: debug  it, perhaps the library is faulty.

Comment: Hi ergonaut, I have created a new project and now it is fine. Something went wrong during the copy of the project. Thanks a lot!